# C# WPF Subscribe to Event in another Class fired from a UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, mainwindow, eventhandler

I have read through a lot of articles to resolve this problem, but I can't get this to work.

The Situation:
I have a WPF MainWindow where I am loading UserControls into it.
The Mainwindow should listen to an EventHandler in a Class called Navigation. The Event will be fired upon certain changes in the UserControls.

So far I can confirm that the UserControls can fire the Event, but the MainWindow does not pickup the Throw.

Navigation Class:

```
public class Navigation
{
    public delegate void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs args);
    public event EventHandler ThrowEvent = delegate { };

    public void NavigationUpdateEvent()
    {
        ThrowEvent(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

UserControl:

```
    public delegate void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs args);
    public event EventHandler ThrowEvent = delegate { };

    Navigation myNavigation = new Navigation();

    public myUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void CheckBox_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (cbCheckBox.IsChecked.Value)
        { 
            UMENavigation.NavigationUpdateEvent();
        }
    }
```

The MainWindow:

```
    private void DoSomething()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("It worked!");
    }

    private Navigation _Thrower;


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _Thrower = new Navigation();
        _Thrower.ThrowEvent += (sender, args) => { DoSomething(); };

    }
```

However, the _Thrower never picks up the Fired Event..

Any help is greatly appreciated! This is starting to hurt :)

Greetings, Tom

Comment: naming wise it should be called RaiseEvent not ThrowEvent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Navigation` instances in `UserControl` and in the `MainWindow` are different.
`UserControl` fires the event for its own instance. At the same time, `MainWindow` listens for the event from *its* own instance.

Either use single instance of `Navigation`, or create a proxy-event in `UserControl` and subscribe it in `MainWindow`.

Besides, you don't need to declare your `EventHandler`. It's already [declared](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Dennis, I have sealed the Navigation class now and it appears to work almost. The MainWindow has subscribed but I just don't get how I can Fire the event from the UserControl. Any hint? Navigation.NavigationUpdateEvent(); no longer works as it requires an object reference :/